# How to change HTTP header for a specific content type?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, ssl, richfaces, flash

I'm using RichFaces and I'm having problems with the fileUpload flash component + IE + SSL. According to research I've done, I need to change "Pragma" and "Cache-Control" HTTP headers.

How can I change those headers only for flash content?
I tried using a Servlet Filter. This is the `doFilter()` method:

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
if (resp.getContentType() != null && resp.getContentType().contains("flash")) { // application/x-shockwave-flash
resp.setHeader("Pragma", "");
}
```

The filter is being executed, the header is being changed, but then I check with firebug, the header is back to "no-cache". This is the last filter I have in my `web.xml` but it is happening like if some other filter was putting the header back.

I'm also using JBoss 5.
How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute the instructions to set the header before the `doFilter()`. In this way:

```
HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
if ( // .. your test ) {
  resp.setHeader("Pragma", "");
}
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Because you cannot set an header field once the server starts sending data to the client.

Naturally in this way you have to find another method to check the *contentType* of the requested resources. Maybe you can do your check based on the [HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) and the filename extension in this value.

Comment: I thought what I did would change the header **after** the server has processed the request, but **before** sending the response. I first tested setting that header for all responses, but just some of them (not including the flash) kept the change.

Comment: No the code in `doFilter` already writes to the client. Sometimes you if you a large buffer for the response it can works, but as you exceed this limit it starts to sending data. So you cannot be sure.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. But I removed the if condition from the filter and added ``<url-pattern>*.swf</url-pattern>``  to the deployment descriptor. Thank you.

Comment: Remember that you can add many `url-pattern` on the same filter if you need.